# Auto display results using json

Tags: json, codeigniter

Currently i'm using json to auto display my reuslt, but i got error say json_encode(): type is unsupported, encoded as null, and i think my problem is view, when i choose in name in dropdown i gives an error json_encode(): type is unsupported, encoded

Model

```
function get_address($name) {
    $vendres = array('name' => $name);
    $this->db->select('address');
    $this->db->where($vendres);
    $this->db->distinct();
    $result = $this->db->get('profile');
    if($result->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach($result->result_array() as $row){
            echo $row['address'];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Controller

```
function address() {
    $name=$this->input->post('name');
    $this->load->model('default/M_profile');
    $data['address'] = $this->M_vendor->get_address($name);
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($data));
    //echo $data;
    return;
}
```

in view i use dropdown.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#profile select').change(function () {
        var add = $(this).text();
        $.ajax({   
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>admin/profile/address",
            method: "POST", 
            data: {profile: add},

            success: function(add) {

                $('#address').val(add);
            }
        })
    });
});
<select name="test">....</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lots of errors:

1.In ajax it should be `type:'POST'`.Not `method:'POST'`.

2.In controller it should be `$this->input->post('profile')`

3.In model just return your data using `result_array()`.

MODEL:

```
function get_address($name) {
    $vendres = array('name' => $name);
    $this->db->select('address');
    $this->db->where($vendres);
    $this->db->distinct();
    $result = $this->db->get('profile');
    if($result->num_rows() > 0){
        return $result->result_array();
        }
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
function address() {
    $name=$this->input->post('profile');
    $this->load->model('default/M_profile');
    $data = $this->M_vendor->get_address($name);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

View:(Ajax):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#profile select').change(function () {
        var add = $(this).text();
        $.ajax({   
            url: "<?php echo base_url('admin/profile/address');?>",
            type: "POST", 
            data: {profile: add},

            success: function(add) {
                var data = JSON.parse(add);//parse response to convert into onject
                console.log(data);//see your result in console
                alert(data[0].address);

            }
        })
    });
});
</script>
<select name="test">....</select>
```

I hope it helps you a lot.

Comment: This is a good answer, I would recommend adding the line: header('Content-Type: application/json'); Just before the "echo json_encode..." in the Controller method. This just enforces the content type returned by the method. I had some issues on IIS before.

Answer (score 0):

you are echoing the result instead of returning

```
    function get_address($name) {
        $vendres = array('name' => $name);
        $this->db->select('address');
        $this->db->where($vendres);
        $this->db->distinct();
        $result = $this->db->get('profile');
        if($result->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach($result->result_array() as $row){
                $result[] = $row['address'];
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```